# Вопрос о двоеточии

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Текст: *"Хичкок был, что называется, ровесником века — он появился на свет в августе 1899-го, умер в апреле 1980-го: застал и королеву Викторию, и премьера Тэтчер".*

https://seance.ru/articles/hitchcock-scared/

Мой вопрос касается постановки двоеточия. Не могу до конца прояснить для себя его постановку в данном предложении. Можно ли отнести его к первой части предложения, т.е. где говорится о "ровеснике века"? Тогда тире отделяет вставную конструкцию или как? Словом, не понимаю. (Извините за сумбурность)

Comment: Было бы лучше поменять тире и двоеточие местами.

Comment: Согласна полностью.

Comment: Парный знак «двоеточие – тире»  в небольшом по объему предложении  неясно читается.

Comment: @Sharon Почему это? Предложение не маленькое, вы даже точку с запятой поставили, что ставится в основном в больших.

Comment: Точка с запятой так себе, мелочь, почти запятая, а два сильных  знака будут конфликтовать между собой.  К примеру, так оформляется  однородный ряд после обобщающего слова. Что это у вас будет, присоединительный оборот в конце предложения?   Не сразу и догадаешься.  Знаки должны представлять  грамматику максимально понятной. Короче говоря, тесно им здесь вместе.

Comment: @Sharon Лучше используйте @, оповещение не приходит. *Точка с запятой так себе, мелочь, почти запятая* — нет, почти точка, поэтому и используется редко. В чём конфликт, если каждый знак используется по назначению? Тире выражает следствие того, что он жил в такой-то период (а запятая там ничего этого не показывает).

Comment: @oleedd  Если нажать на "отслеживать", то уведомления приходят и без @. У меня всегда срабатывает.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Александр, я доверяю вашему художественном вкусу. Скажите, какой вариант  из трех выглядит лучше, выразительнее, какой вам  нравится больше?  Я именно о графике говорю. А чем запись красивее, тем она и правильнее, не правда ли?

Comment: @Sharon Чтоб пришло оповещение, при @ обязательно нужно убрать пробел, если ник состоит из двух слов (вы не убрали).

Comment: @Sharon Какая ещё графика? Графического принципа в пунктуации не существует. Вот уж от кого не ожидал, так это от вас. Помню, как вы выступали против графического тире. Вот где символьная графика применяется: https://www.google.com/search?q=рисунки+из+символов&source=lnms&tbm=isch

Comment: @oleedd  Неважно – пробел-безпробел – главное отслеживать :)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Да это понял, но это меня касается. Но откуда мне знать, что человек, которому отвечаю, отслеживает? Откуда мне знать, что вы отслеживаете? Поэтому надо обращение (и без пробела), если хочешь, чтоб человек наверняка прочитал.

Comment: @Sharon  Сначала, прочитав вопрос, я тоже хотел поменять местами тире и двоеточие. Потом увидел ваш ответ и отметил его. Я вообще, в таких случаях, когда возможно равноправие знаков, предпочитаю тире – мне эта тенденция в письме нравится: двоеточие я "плохо вижу" :)  Графически красивый вариант данного предложения пока не вырисовался...

Comment: @oleedd  Да, согласен полностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Двоеточие в этом месте предложения — явная ошибка. Вот все правила, по которым ставится двоеточие:

> § 159. Двоеточие ставится перед перечислением, которым заканчивается предложение:
>
> 1. Если перечислению предшествует обобщающее слово (а нередко, кроме того, ещё слова *например, как-то, а именно*), например:
>
> *Отовсюду поднялись казаки: от Чигирина, от Переяслава, от Батурина, от
> Глухова, от низовой стороны днепровской и от всех его верховий и
> островов* (Гоголь).
>
> *Выступили знакомые подробности: оленьи рога, полки
> с книгами, зеркало, печь с отдушником, который давно надо было
> починить, отцовский диван, большой стол, на столе открытая книга,
> сломанная пепельница, тетрадь с его почерком* (Л. Толстой).
>
> *Острогою бьётся крупная рыба, как-то: щуки, сомы, жерехи, судаки* (С. Аксаков).
>
> 2. Если перед перечислением нет обобщающего слова, но необходимо предупредить читателя, что далее следует какой-либо перечень, например:
>
> *Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и
> ещё кой-какие привлекательные узелки и коробочки* (Л. Толстой).
>
> § 160. Двоеточие ставится перед перечислением, находящимся в середине
> предложения, если перечислению предшествует обобщающее слово или слова
> *как-то, например, а именно,* например:
>
> *И всё это: и река, и прутья верболаза, и этот мальчишка — напомнило мне далёкие
> дни детства* (Первенцев).
>
> § 161. Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно
> или несколько предложений, не соединённых с первым посредством союзов
> и заключающих в себе:
>
> а) разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чём говорится в первом
> предложении, например:
>
> *Я не ошибся: старик не отказался от предлагаемого стакана* (Пушкин).
>
> *Сверх того, заботы большого семейства беспрестанно мучили её: то кормление
> грудного ребёнка не шло, то нянька ушла, то, как теперь, заболел один из детей*
> (Л. Толстой).
>
> *Тут открылась картина довольно занимательная: широкая сакля, которой
> крыша опиралась на два закопчённые столба, была полна народа* (Лермонтов).
>
> б) основание, причину того, о чём говорится в первом предложении,
> например:
>
> *Не нагнать тебе бешеной тройки: кони сыты, и крепки, и бойки*
> (Некрасов).
>
> *Недаром боги греческие признавали над собою неотразимую
> власть судьбы: судьба — это была та тёмная граница, за которую не
> переступало сознание древних* (Белинский).
>
> § 162. Двоеточие ставится между двумя предложениями, не соединёнными посредством
> союзов, если в первом предложении такими глаголами, как *видеть, смотреть,
> слышать, знать, чувствовать* и т. п., делается предупреждение, что далее
> последует изложение какого-нибудь факта или какое-нибудь описание,
> например:
>
> *И вот бакенщик и помощник-киргиз видят: плывут по реке две лодки* (А. Н.
> Толстой).
>
> *Пополз я по густой траве вдоль по оврагу, смотрю: лес кончился, несколько казаков
> выезжают из него на поляну, и вот выскакивает прямо к ним мой Карагёз...*
> (Лермонтов).
>
> *Вот, наконец, мы взобрались на Гуд-гору, остановились и оглянулись: на ней висело
> серое облако, и его холодное дыхание грозило близкой бурею...*
> (Лермонтов).
>
> *Я знаю: в вашем сердце есть и гордость, и прямая честь* (Пушкин).
>
> *Павел чувствует: чьи-то пальцы дотрагиваются до его руки выше локтя* (Н.
> Островский).
>
> Но (без оттенка предупреждения): *Слышу, земля задрожала* (Некрасов).
>
> § 163. Двоеточие ставится после предложения, вводящего прямую речь, в
> частности — прямой вопрос или восклицание, например:
>
> *Минуты две они молчали, но к ней Онегин подошёл и молвил: «Вы ко мне писали, не
> отпирайтесь»* (Пушкин).
>
> *По окончании работы Пётр спросил Ибрагима: «Нравится ли тебе девушка, с которой
> ты танцевал менуэт на прошедшей ассамблее?»* (Пушкин).
>
> *А я думал: «Какой это тяжёлый и ленивый малый!»* (Чехов).
>
> https://therules.ru/colon/

Ничего этого у нас нет. Зато можно рассматривать придаточное предложение *он появился на свет в августе 1899-го* как пояснение к главному предложению *Хичкок был, что называется, ровесником века*. Вот здесь как раз следовало бы поставить двоеточие.

А там, где поставил двоеточие автор предложения, на самом деле нужны: во-1-х, **запятая,** закрывающая ряд распространённых однородных членов предложения, во-2-х, **тире** перед частью придаточного предложения, выражающей следствие.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше было бы оформить предложение следующим образом:

***Хичкок был, что называется, ровесником века — он появился на свет в августе 1899-го, умер в апреле 1980-го;  застал и королеву Викторию, и премьера Тэтчер.***

**Пояснение**

1. **Тире** здесь заменяет **пояснительное двоеточие**, но при этом не требует значительно  увеличенной (предупредительной) паузы, а это лучше соответствует и стилю текста, и структуре самого предложения.
2. Далее ставим **точку с запятой**, обозначая, с одной стороны, новые детали и подробности, а с другой – раскрывая **ту же идею «ровесника века».**

Поэтому два знака (двоеточия и тире) здесь не нужны (они будут мешать друг другу).

**Дополнение**

Второй вариант (двоеточие вместо тире, остальное — через запятые)

*Хичкок был, что называется, ровесником века: он появился на свет в августе 1899-го, умер в апреле 1980-го, застал и королеву Викторию, и премьера Тэтчер.*

Answer (score 0):

По поводу **ЯВНОЙ ОШИБКИ** про постановке двоеточия для обозначения **пояснительных отношений**.

Привожу текст статьи **для тех, кто может быть этого не знает**. Пусть почитает,  хотя информация **общеизвестная**. Впрочем, здесь нужен интонационный анализ, а это уже немного другой уровень знаний.

**§ 72. Вариативные знаки препинания**     Двоеточие — тире

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189

5. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с **пояснительными отношениями**: Авторов этих писем волновали разные проблемы, но объединяло одно (: —) все они ждали от газеты конкретной и действенной помощи; Всех интересовал только один вопрос (: —) как поскорее выпутаться из создавшегося положения; Я помню пушок на его щеках (: —) он только начал бриться; На голове её цветной платок (: —) по алому полю зелёные розы; У меня правило (: —) никакого кофепития перед сном.

Ср. постановку тире вместо ожидаемого двоеточия: В небе выскакивают беленькие точки — рвутся шрапнели (Кат.); С берёз крупными слезами сыплются капли — идут весенние соки (Кат.).

Comment: Это да, но во всех примерах этого пункта (где два варианта) можно вставить "а именно", что не подходит после "1980-го". Может быть, там что-то другое. Ожидал, что у кого-то будет версия (особенно у вас), но все молчат.

Comment: А зачем вам это "а именно". Сказано же  – пояснительные отношения!  Автор сразу начинает пояснять и объяснять, почему он ровесник века. Можете поставить тире, а можете двоеточие.  Розенталь дает вам свободу действий,  интонационные характеристики у знаков разные. Это о ведь не школа для детей, где все по правилам, а  художественное творчество, где автор подбирает нужный ему ритм речи. Вам ли это объяснять!

Comment: На самом деле это важный фактор, Розенталь говорил, что при пояснении можно вставить "а именно". Я, как и Егор, о двоеточии именно после "1980-го". А после "века" — можно и то и другое, но двоеточие там может указывать на причину.

Comment: После "века" пояснительное тире не сильно подходит, оно обычно поясняет какое-то слово, а всё остальное можно откинуть, сделав определение понятия со словом "это", например: *вопрос  — это как поскорее выпутаться из создавшегося положения; правило — это никакого кофепития перед сном; объединяло одно — это то, что все они ждали от газеты конкретной и действенной помощи*. Так что тире после "века" больше как интонационное. Это продвинутый уровень (самое редкое и ценное), так что отнеситесь серьёзно, не все такие нюансы сам Розенталь замечал, а то всем было бы гораздо проще.

Comment: Вы знаете интонационные характеристики знаков? Пояснительное тире отличается от двоеточия более короткой паузой – и это всё! Не хотите держать паузу, как в театре – значит, ставьте тире, а не двоеточие. Будьте художником слова, чувствуйте язык.

Comment: Нет, это не всё. Перед двоеточием понижение интонации, интонация предупреждения о порции информации (в общем, по стандарту).